# Evil Spam Emails caused hosting account suspension!

Tags: web-hosting, email, spam

We have a couple domains hosted [rackservers.com.au](http://www.rackservers.com.au). Recently our account go suspended without any notice.

I then filed a ticket and soon got the answer:'There are some one forging email accounts from your domain, and they have been sending out spam emails. So we do not want you here anymore, take your backup and go.'

I am quite shocked by such attitude and more confused by the actions we should take under such situation.

Should I take my back up and go?
Should I ask them for more details?
How can I prevent this from happening again in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Ask for more details. If a misconfiguration or a security problem on your site allowed a spammer to use your site/account you will face the same problem in the future.

You need to discover what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before when I was trying to get the answer out of one of the staff, he was saying that the problem is us, that someone knows us and did all this. I am pretty sure my website is either famous nor notorious at all, there is no promotion or whatever done to it. And we do not use email service of that domain. It sounds really dodge...

Comment: Did you feel that you send mass message? If you are in shared environment, most of providers dont allow you to send mass message, as their IP will be blocked. But, you can contact them and ask for the explanation first. I hope you can solve this problem well. :)

Comment: I am not getting any reply from that no good hosting company...I am a bit stuck...what would you do in this case?

Comment: What about phone support? Call them. If you still dont get answer, with very sorry you need to find another provider.

Comment: @MarkShawn If they don't answer it is another sign that another provider will be a much better choice :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know that in cPanel (which is the deFacto control panel for many hosts) there is a button called "email authentication" which contains the options to enable DomainKeys and SPF Authentication.

Both of those are industry standards used by many email servers which essentially verify emails from your domain actually originate from your servers IP. If the emails are forged, they would be flagged as spam.

Additionally you might want to contact your host they use a different control panel - because then they'll be able to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I did contact them but there is no answer, they are really not helpful...they suspended our cP as well...:(